# Host spring java web app to Openshift

Tags: java, spring-mvc, openshift

[image]

**home.jsp**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>This is My HOME.</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Actually, It should show like below.

[image]

> How to call my webpage in openshift?

Answer (score 0):

On which server you have deployed this tomcat or Jboss ?.

Comment: Spring Tool Suite, Pivotal Server.

Comment: Sometime how the webapp is deployed on server at our local and on open shift is different . From your it seems to me that your conetxt path is different . I would suggest you to go inside the container and checker whether the application is depoloyed on the same path or different.

Comment: Hi ishantg, how to check is it on the same path or different?

Comment: I don't have much knowledge about the pivotal server. But i can give you some idea how it happens in tomcat. whenever you deploy any new application on tomcat a new folder with the name as gave  is being under webapp folder on tomcat server . But sometime it does not due to diff kind of configuration(it happened with me when i deployed my applicaiton on Openshift) might be case with you as well

Answer (score 0):

What comes to mind first is the difference in URLs, leading to different way of processing JSP file. The top one is:

```
..../????-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT
```

while the bottom one:

```
..../aaaa/hello
```

clearly has different context and endpoint.

There might be differences in configuration of your local server and the remote one, but I'd start from comparing apples to apples first - same JSP, same application, same URL path.

Comment: But "hello" is not. Please double check the "aaaa" too, as it seems to me it's not the same. By the same, I mean literally. Try using the same path on both your localhost and the remote.